# The best solution for control access to models in strongLoop

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm new in StrongLoop.
I have 2 models(`CustomUser` and `Item`).
I want any `CustomUser` has access to his `Items`.
I don't want use default APIs exposed by StrongLoop because i don't want CustomUsers able to define filter with these APIs.
I define my RemoteMethod that returns items based on a internal filter.
My question:
Should i check current user and return his related items or can i use ACL in StrongLoop for this matter?
If the ACL is correct answer, where should i insert my RemoteMethod(`CustomUser` model or `Item` model) and how to define correct settings for use of ACL?

Comment: Do you want to disable public access for `CustomUsers` ?

Comment: Yes. i want only enable access for my RemoteMethod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,it's possible. Loopback is very flexible.

Of course, you asked 2 different question.

1. How to disable apply 'where' filter in api.
2. How CustomUser can access to just his items.

---

For the first question, you can use loopback hooks and set where filters based on whatever you want.in this way, you don't compel to write new remote method.

### Item.json:

```
Item.observe('access', function limitToTenant(ctx, next) {
 ...
 ctx.query.where.tenantId = loopback.getCurrentContext().tenantId;
...
 next();
});
```

---

And for next question you must use some acls and relations for your two models like this:

First, disable to access all remote methods in `Item.json` model.

```
"acls": [
 {
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY"
 }
]
```

next in `CustomUser.json` model define which methods of Item model can be used:

```
"acls": [
    {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$owner",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "__create__items"
    },
    {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$owner",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "__get__items"
    },
    {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$owner",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "__count__items"
    }
    ...
]
```

next, define a relation between CustomUser and Item model.

### in Item.json

```
"relations": {
    "customUser": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "CustomUser",
    "foreignKey": "ownerId"
    }
}
```

### in CustomUser.json:

```
"relations": {
    "items": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "Item",
    "foreignKey": "ownerId"
    }    
}
```

Then create new user and login with received accessToken and keep userId for next steps.

Now if you want to post new Item you can use this api.

```
POST (items data) : api/CustomUser/{userId}/items/
```

And to get his items you can use:

```
GET : api/CustomUser/{userId}/items/
```

In this way ownerId will be saved automatically in Item model and each other users can't access his Items.

Comment: Thank you. In second way, can i use RemoteMethod instead of basic API and set ACL for ir?

Comment: Yes,you can define remote method with own acl and relate it to Item model.

Answer (score 0):

As per the loopback [documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Exposing+models+over+REST) each method has to be disabled separately.

```
var isStatic = true;
CustomUser.disableRemoteMethod('deleteById', isStatic);
```

But remote methods can be called even if it is disabled.

ACLs are required only if you intend to perform any [authorisation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Accessing+related+models) control.